# Search result UI is not visible on the UI

Tags: flutter

I have a search option in my UI and after search I need to show the search result on the UI.

My code:

```
class SearchResultPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SearchResultPage();

  @override
  State<SearchResultPage> createState() => _SearchResultPageState();
}

class _SearchResultPageState extends State<SearchResultPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: MyAppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SearchBox(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchBox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SearchBox> createState() => _SearchBoxState();
}

class _SearchBoxState extends State<SearchBox> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.search, // Shows a search button
                onSubmitted: (value) {
                  // Handle search action here
                  performSearch(context);
                },
                //remaining styles of searchbox
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }

  SafeArea performSearch(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          WordDetails(),
          const SizedBox(height: 5),
          DictionaryUsersList(),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: WordMeaning(),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My problem is after search, the search result UI under `performSearch` is not visible on the UI.

I tried modifying the `performSearch` method to return a `Column` directly, without wrapping it in a `SafeArea` and added `performSearch(context)` within the `setState` method, but no luck.

**Update**

I have tried the `SearchDelegate` like below:

```
onSubmitted: (value) {
  // Handle search action here
  showSearch(context: context, delegate: CustomSearchDelegate());
}

class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate{
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  //Added my search result UI here
  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // Implement your search logic here
    // You can use the query variable to get the search query
    // Example: performSearch(context, query);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          WordDetails(),
          const SizedBox(height: 5),
          DictionaryUsersList(),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: WordMeaning(),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    // You can show suggestions while the user is typing
    // Example: showSuggestions(context, query);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Here I found 4 override functions: `buildActions, buildLeading, buildResults and buildSuggestions`.

I have added my search result UI under `buildResults` function, but after search a new UI with search UI is appearing and if I again search the result is showing on that page. How can I show the results on previous page itself?

Comment: that's now how you show an ui ! Heres duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75397351/how-to-show-search-results-below-my-search-bar)

Comment: @OMiShah I have updated the question with new findings, could you please check.

Answer (score 0):

Returning widget through the function wont show it in the UI, try this

```
TextField(
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.search, // Shows a search button
                    onSubmitted: (value) {
                      // Handle search action here
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Scaffold(child: performSearch(context))));
                    },
                    //remaining styles of searchbox
                  ),
```

Comment: Getting the below error: `The argument type 'Scaffold Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)'.`  I already have a 'Scaffold' function on SearchResultPage, so is it possible to add multiple 'Scaffold'?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Still getting error: Check the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Kp2.png

Comment: I have updated the question with new findings, could you please check.